# html.validation asp.net razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

How can I add a simple validation in my code? If `value = 0` I don't want the controller to process the form. If anything else is selected except 0, I want the controller to process the form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateReport", "Admin", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <select id="reportId" name="reportId" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Religion</option>
        <option value="2">Address</option>
        <option value="3">Job</option>
        <option value="4">Degree</option>
        <option value="7">Age</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Print" id="rlist_type" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This article provides basic information on ASP.NET MVC 5 validation
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

I would leave the value for the first option empty then add a [Required] attribute on the object that I was using to capture the form post.

```
public class AdminScreenFormPost
{
    [Required]
    public int reportId { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the controller add

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View();
}
```

In the razor view add this so it will displays the validation results

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

I would also look into ModelState.AddModelError

```
ModelState.AddModelError("MyDropDownListKey", "Please Select");
```

Comment: Wow! super thanks @Nathan Smith. Now it's working :D